# Python: How can I disable add-ins in Outlook and Excel?

Tags: python, excel, outlook, outlook-addin, excel-addins

I have some add-ins that load on start up. I can't disable this from happening as I don't have administrator rights.

I am writing a program that opens outlook and sends emails, but it is slowed down by these add ins. Is there a way to programmatically disable add-ins after opening outlook using python (e.g. using the win32com package)?

I need to do the same thing for Excel too. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't actually need Outook to be able to send emails in Python. You could use e.g. https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib instead

Comment: End users want to see the email so they can review and hit send manually. Lack of trust for machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the addins by setting the `LoadBehavior` value appropriately for the problematic addins in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: This is only valid for per-user add-ins. It will not affect 'system' COM add-ins (set in HKLM).

Answer (score 0):

Well the first advice is try to have the **administrator rights** on your computer to run the py script with no issue

secondly i think there is a way to do this as i came across a py lib in github but getting the administrative rights it better as it will be a issue in the future

Comment: I think this option is a no go, as admin rights will not be given to the end users.

Comment: hmm i think so well i was thinking your using your computer

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use Outlook, would running it in **safe mode** be sufficient?

If so, you can use the command line parameter `/safe`, for example:

```
outlook.exe /safe
```

[Reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/launching-word-without-add-ins-via-command-line/a378a7e2-105f-407d-8577-c2bf79b87eaa)